# Why is the negative $l^p$ norm like function convex when $0 < p < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

Let

$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{p}x^p &, \mbox{ if } x \geq 0, \mbox{ where } 0 < p < 1, \\
\infty &, \mbox{ if } x < 0.
\end{cases}$$

I want to show convexity of this function. This is my approach so far:

let us assume $x, y > 0$. Given $t \in (0, 1)$, we have
$$
\varphi(tx + (1 - t)y) = -\frac{1}{p}(tx + (1 - t)y)^p
$$
and
$$
t\varphi(x) + (1 - t) \varphi(y) = -\frac{t}{p} x^p - \frac{(1 - t)}{p}y^p = -\frac{1}{p}(tx^p + (1 - t) y^p). 
$$
Now we show
$$
(tx + (1 - t)y)^p \geq (tx^p + (1 - t)y^p).
$$
Then we have
$$
tx + (1 - t)y \geq (tx^p + (1 - t)y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
I am not sure how to show this. It seems like Holder inequality, but I am not sure how one would apply it here. I am looking for an approach **without** using derivatives. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that $x^{p}$ is concave on $[0,\infty)$ for $0<p<1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am aware of this fact, but I'll need to show it. I would imagine the proof would go somewhat like this as well?

Comment: I can almost bet that you cannot prove it without using derivatives.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What is causing this difficulty? I am aware that the positive version of this with $1 < p < \infty$ could be proven without derivatives using Holder. What is making this one different?

Comment: Can Holder's inequality be proved without using derivatives?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I might be forgetting the proof for Holder. We are using convexity somewhere in the proof, right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It depends on whether you think $\log(x) \leq x-1$ and $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$ require derivatives to be proven.  (I could be reasonably convinced that no matter the definition of the natural logarithm used, at least one of those needs derivatives)

Comment: @BrianMoehring According to me those inequalities cannot be proved without derivatives.  The present question asking for a proof without derivatives hardly makes any sense to me.